How to use state value of a child component
By looking the code you may see what I'm trying to do, but it's not working.
I want to import the Header component into the MainPart component, and then use the "value" function from Header in the current file.
Did not work by doing Header.value in the MainPart file.
MainPart file:
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";

const MainPart = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{Header.value}</h1>
        </div>  
    );
};

export default MainPart;


Header file:
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Header = () => {
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
   const [value, setValue] = useState("")
   const addValue = () => {
      setValue(inputValue)
   }
   const handleChange = (e) => {
      setInputValue(e.target.value)
   }
    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center flex-col items-center border-b-2 border-blue-500">
            <h1 className="text-white text-5xl mt-5">To-Do List</h1>
            <div className=" flex mt-5 gap-2 h-8">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add something"
                    className="rounded-md text-xl focus:outline-none pl-2 box-border"
               value={inputValue}
               onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button
                    onClick={addValue}
                    className="bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-md w-20 text-xl h-8">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;


Expect it to show the value from the other file in the MainPart file

I do not think react works this way, what you want to do is create a common parent to both component and put the value state there, pass a handler function with a parameter  to the Header for it to set the value there and then the value to the MainPart.

To access the value state from the Header component in the MainPart component, you need to pass it as a prop.
MainPart.js:
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";

const MainPart = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header value={value} />
            <h1>{value}</h1>
        </div>  
    );
};

export default MainPart;

Header.js:
   import React, { useState } from "react";

   const Header = ({ value }) => {
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
   const [value, setValue] = useState("")
   const addValue = () => {
      setValue(inputValue)
   }
   const handleChange = (e) => {
      setInputValue(e.target.value)
   }
    return (
        <div className="flex justify-center flex-col items-center border-b-2 border-blue-500">
            <h1 className="text-white text-5xl mt-5">To-Do List</h1>
            <div className=" flex mt-5 gap-2 h-8">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add something"
                    className="rounded-md text-xl focus:outline-none pl-2 box-border"
               value={inputValue}
               onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button
                    onClick={addValue}
                    className="bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-800 rounded-md w-20 text-xl h-8">
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;

In the MainPart component, I import the Header component and then render it, passing the value prop. This prop will now be accessible in the Header component as value. You can then use this value prop in your Header component to display it or perform any other desired operations.
Make sure to replace value in the MainPart component with the actual value you want to pass to the Header component.

Did you generated this answer using a tool like ChatGPT?

No, i did this by myself
